# assign 3 different printers on same page(same form) with 3 different print button

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

So.. on the same page, I made 3 different panels. In each pattern, there are texts in 3 different textboxes and there is a printer button to print. I want to assign a different printer for each button. I made 3 different PrintPreviewDialogs each assigned for each panel as well as 3 different printDocument assigned for each panel. When I preview, each shows each panel correctly except for the printer part. How do I accomplish this?

my code is basically similar to this but it doesn't change my default printer setting.

```
using System.Drawing.Printing;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

    public static class myPrinters
    {
        [DllImport("winspool.drv", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    }
    private void printDocument1(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs ev)
    {
        myPrinters.SetDefaultPrinter("Printer1");
        printDocument1.Print(); 
    }

    private void printDocument2(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs ev)
    {
        myPrinters.SetDefaultPrinter("Printer2");
        printDocument2.Print(); 
    }

    private void printDocument3(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs ev)
    {
        myPrinters.SetDefaultPrinter("Printer3");
        printDocument3.Print(); 
    }
```

Comment: Select the printer through `printDocument1.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = "PrinterNr";` You don't need to change the default printer in this context.

Comment: you were right. thx.

Comment: Most welcome and good luck.